# a href not working in mobile format

Tags: html, css

I've been working on my website the entire day but now I suddenly noticed that in mobile format my  buttons (the logo and the menu button they are called #logo and #menu-icon) don't work anymore. The used to work some time ago. And in the desktop (over 768 pixel wide) version they all work fine.

```css
/*--------STYLE.CSS--------*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:300,500,700');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #424949;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 250%;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2%;
}
p {
  font-size: 160%;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 150%;
  padding: 3%;
  text-indent: 2%;
  text-align: justify;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}
header {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  width: 100%;
  height: 86px;
}
#header-inner {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#logo {
  margin: -5px 0 -5px 20px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;/*top right bottom left*/
  float: left;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  background: url(img/logohead96x.png) no-repeat center;   /*org img/logo128x.png*/
}
nav {
  float: right;
  padding: 4px 20px 0 0;
}
#menu-icon {
  display: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url(img/nav.png) center;
}
a:hover#menu-icon {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
nav ul li {
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
nav ul li a {
  color:#f5f5f5;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 25px;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #707b7c;
}
.current {
  color: #707b7c;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; /*calc(100% - 86px - 29px)*/
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container-inner {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container img {
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container video {
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
footer {
  background: #1a1a1a;
  width: 100%;
}
.social {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.social li {
  display: inline;
}
.social i {
  font-size: 460%;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 5% 5% 5% 4%;
  color: #707b7c
}
.social i:hover {
  color: #f5f5f5;
}
footer.second {
  background-color: #424949;
  margin: 0;
}
footer.second p {
  margin: 4px 0 0 0; /*top right bottom left*/
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 130%;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}


/*--------MEDIA--------*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  h2 {
    font-size: 150%;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 120%;
  }
  header {
    position: absolute;
  }
  #logo {
    margin: -5px 5px -5px 5px;
    background: url(img/logohead64x.png) no-repeat center;
  }
  #menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav {
    padding: 25px;
  }
  nav ul, nav:active ul {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #1a1a1a;
    right: 20px;
    top: 60px;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    width: 40%;
  }
  nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
  nav li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  }
  .banner {
    padding-top: 86px;
  }
  .social i {
    font-size: 180%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Home page of slothy.cloud -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--
 My small cozy website.
  © veryslothysloth 2018
-->
 <head>
  <!-- Links -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="img/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="img/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="img/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#2e86c1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- Open Graph Protocol -->
  <meta property="og:url" content="://slothy.cloud" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="slothy.cloud | by veryslothysloth" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="A small slothy website." />
  <meta property="og:image" content="img/slothyicon.png" />
  <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="img/slothyicon.png" />

  <!-- Twitter card -->
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="slothy.cloud |by veryslothysloth">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="A small slothy website.">
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="img/slothyicon.png">
  <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="img/slothyicon.png">

  <!-- Data -->
  <title>slothy.cloud | by veryslothysloth</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="A small slothy website.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="sloth,slothy,veryslothysloth,file,upload,hosting,lolisafe">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2d89ef">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#aed6f1">
 </head>

 <body>
  <header>
   <!-- Header -->
   <div id="header-inner">
    <a href="index.html" id="logo"></a>
    <nav>
     <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cloud</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stat</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </header>


  <!-- Main Body -->
  <div class="container">
   <video loop>
    <source src="img/alley.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
   <!--<div class="container-inner">
    <p>Test Text</p>
   </div>-->
  </div>


  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer>
   <ul class="social">
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/veryslothysloth" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/veryslothysloth/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/veryslothysloth" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-steam"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="mailto:contact@slothy.cloud" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
  </footer>

  <!-- Second Footer -->
  <footer class="second">
   <p>&copy; veryslothysloth</p>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

This may be a completely stupid mistake or small typo but I'm quite tired and can't seem to figure this out myself with my really limited coding skills... I'm quite new to all this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div .container lies over the nav and menu-icon. So the hover doesnt works.

add a z-index to the header to solve it

```
header {
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what "they don't work" means, but it does stand out that one of the links is to `index.html` and the other is to `#`. The first will reload the current page (assuming the HTML you provided is `index.html`, the second will scroll the current page to the top. What behavior are you seeing, and what behavior are you looking for?

Comment: They both now do what they were supposed to again thanks to the comment from Xübecks, one brings you back to the start page (currently only page index.html) and the other opens a pop up menu.